# JavaScript communication between 2 windows

Tags: javascript

I am using `window.open` to open 2 new windows from my web page and these 2 new windows are of different domains. My requirement is that from one window I want to change the URL of the other window and vice versa. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: yes, you use postMessage to talk to the opener from both windows.

Comment: If it's cross domain, you'll most likely have issues using `opener`

Comment: You can try `window.location` (javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Have a look at [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

The syntax looks like:

```
otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);
```

Where `otherWindow` is a reference to another window. `window.open` returns such a reference.